# Get product id from custom unique attribute magento

Tags: php, magento

In my magento site,i have created an attribute named barcode and is set unique just as sku. Is there any code to get product id from the barcode value.ie, if the barcode i assigned for a product is 12121, then i need to get the product id based on that value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called **loadByAttribute** of model **Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract** (line 224) that you can use like that :

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('barcode', '12121');
```

**Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract** is extended by **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product**